# Overlapping text in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter. The text of the two text widgets "PROGRESS_SUPPORT_TITLE" and "PROGRESS_SUPPORT_DESCRIPTION" (see in the code below) are overlapping themselves in some browsers.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2EKO.png)

The problem occurs only in some browsers. For instance the screenshot is taken from the in-app browser of the android facebook app.

This is the associated source-code:

```
class SupportProgressScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SupportProgressScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AnalyticsService.logEvent(context,
        eventName: 'SUPPORT_PROGRESS_SCREEN',
        category: TrackingEventCategory.APP);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: const EddyAppBarWidget(
          isFullScreenAppBar: true,
          preventBackButton: true,
        ),
        backgroundColor: EddyShopConstants.whiteColorEddy,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: EddyShopConstants.columnContentPaddingEddy)
              .add(const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10)),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              const Spacer(),
              Text(
                'PROGRESS_SUPPORT_TITLE'.i18n,
                style: EddyShopConstants.ctaTextStyleEddy,
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              Center(
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  EddyShopConstants.WORKING_ON_IT_SVG,
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              Text(
                'PROGRESS_SUPPORT_DESCRIPTION'.i18n,
                style: EddyShopConstants.primaryTextStyleEddy,
              ),
              const Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

The text should be displayed normal and not overlap.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          EddyShopConstants.WORKING_ON_IT_SVG,
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'PROGRESS_SUPPORT_DESCRIPTION'.i18n,
      style: EddyShopConstants.primaryTextStyleEddy,
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please clearify you solution, what is the change in code and how it is solving the issue